# Zombie process actually slowing system down ~100 fold

Tags: cpu, zombie

I was using vlc and started up another vlc which did not actually start.
System became slow. I checked top and noticed that vlc had become a zombie.
top was showing vlc to be 99-101% cpu which was changing in value but near 100%. I could not open up a Qterminal. I decided to read up on zombie processes. I noted that people were saying cpu may read 100% but actual resources would not be used. Memory in top did show zero for vlc zombie.
 I tried to renice to 39 which top shown was done. 
The system was about 100 times as slow as normal. I decided to open up lightweight terminal rvxt and sudo reboot. After one minute no change in the screen so I did a hard power restart.

What should I do to collect more information and how can I monitor this to produce data for say a bug report?

Lubuntu: LXQT : Laptop HP Pavilion dv9000 2Gb Ram
Linux ub2 4.18.0-10-generic #11-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 11 15:13:55 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Should vlc be started that way?

Comment: Good point, I did not say how I started vlc. I started vlc from the spacefm file manager by opening a video file. Vlc preferences can allow more than one instance.

Comment: Then that's perhaps a bug report!

Comment: Yes the zombie might only happen on a 2nd or more vlc starting. I was concerned that the greater bug is in the OS as zombie processes according to my understanding should have zero resource use. Not only was the process at 100% but the scheduler was not controlling the process either. The process was acting in real time scheduling mode and effectively locking resources or at least slowing them down. As I said was unable to soft reboot.